# Dell XPS Running Windows 8.1 Not Entering Sleep Mode --> Shuts Down

Tags: windows-8.1, sleep, dell-xps

Recently, my Dell XPS running windows 8.1 (which had been upgraded from Win7) attempts to go into sleep mode but just shuts down (without properly closing documents or browsers).  Any advise?

Answer (score 0):

Check your power settings, there are three different things you can do:

1 hibernate, your PC saves it's current state to disk and turns off the hardware. Fans stop spinning etc and you have to hit the power button and wait about 30 seconds for it to turn back on. I believe this is the default power saving mode on Win8 so you could be mistaking this for shutting down entirely or maybe your PC doesn't support hibernate and shuts down instead of hibernating.

2 Sleep, this is basically just the computer shutting off non essential hardware but it keeps your information stored in the RAM to quickly start working again.

3 monitor off, all that happens is your monitor turns off. Your PC will still be processing things and could be using full power it just doesn't display anything on the monitor and saves the monitor power.

Try picking a different power setting and see if it works better or if you just confused hibernate for a full shut down.

Answer (score 0):

First press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> and type power. Next, click "change what the power button does." In the top of the page, you have an option called "change settings that are currently available". Click the setting.

Below, check the sleep mode in the shutdown setting and save.

Comment: Sleep mode is checked and power settings all appear to be correct.  I think something happened caused by a scheduled microsoft update.